# I made a guard and deployed it for safe-contracts 1.4.1, but when I tried to add it I realized safe still uses 1.3.0

Tags: gnosis-safe

basically the title, I tried to add a guard to my safe (for testing purposes) and I realized that the safe made on the safe website was 1.3.0, how can I deploy a 1.4.1 safe and if I managed to do it, will I not be able to use it on the safe

Comment: Safe guards should be compatible between 1.3.0 and 1.4.1 safes. There were no guard API changes.

Comment: I set my guard to inherit from baseGuard, it didn't exist back then, so I changed it to the guard interface from 1.3.0 and commented out the `checkModuleTransaction` and it worked

Comment: checkModuleTransaction doesn't exist in 1.3.0 or 1.4.1

Comment: Interesting, it's on main, but not in 1.4.1, I thought main was 1.4.1 https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/8ffae95faa815acf86ec8b50021ebe9f96abde10/contracts/base/GuardManager.sol#L46C1-L52C47